# @Document Annotation for Collection Name in MongoDb for Java models Generated through Swagger in Spring boot Application

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-codegen

Steps I am following

1. I write Swagger File for API contract and Definition models for my Microservice
2. Now I am using Swagger codegen dependencies in my Spring boot application to generate Models from reading the Swagger from URL where it is hosted in target (output directory mentioned in pom.xml) directory of my application on "mvn install".
3. For each definition in the Swagger file One model class will be generated in my application's target directory.
4. Now I am using mongoDB as database for models to save as collection.
5. Need to Give @Document(value = "collection-name") - dynamically for model classes.
6. As model class are generated through Swagger codegen cant edit those,

So how to Maintain Dynamic Name for definitions which I want to save in DB
Is there any way through Swagger Contract to define this ?

Answer (score 0):

A while ago I was struggling with this same problem, and [some solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54537046/how-to-generate-swagger-codegen-java-models-as-jpa-entities) include post-processing the generated files.

However, as a security concern, exposing the MongoDB model to the API might not be completely right.  An interesting approach would be to simply use Mappers and apply the DTO concept to the auto-generated model classes.

For instance:

Suppose you have a **users** collection in MongoDB, and an API to retrieve the users.

```
components:
  schemas:
    User:
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          type: string
        name:
          type: string
```

The Swagger auto-generated class would be something like this:

```
package api;

@ApiModel()
@Validated
public class User   {
  @JsonProperty("id")
  private String id = null;

  @JsonProperty("name")
  private String name = null;
}
```

You will also have the 'standard' User model class:

```
package model;

@Document(collection = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    private String id;
    @NotNull
    private String name;
    @NotNull
    private String password;
}
```

Notice for example, that the password field is not included in the API definition.

Then we'll have the typical User repository:

```
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String> { }
```

Now we have to implement the mapper, which is very straightforward using [MapStruct](https://mapstruct.org/):

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE)
public interface UserMapper {
    api.User map(model.User user);
}
```

You can widely customize which and how to map the information.

The only thing remaining is the controller:

```
@Controller
public class MyController implements MyApi {

    @Inject
    UserMapper mapper;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repository;

    @GetMapping("/api/v1.0/users")
    public ResponseEntity<List<api.User>> getAllUsers() {
        List<api.User> users = new ArrayList<>();
        repository.findAll().forEach(user -> users.add(mapper.map(user)));
        return new ResponseEntity(users, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```