# OpenApi-generator do not insert @NotBlank annotation for string

Tags: java, spring, openapi, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I use `openapi-generator-maven-plugin:7.1.0` with properties:

```
<interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
<skipDefaultInterface>true</skipDefaultInterface>
<useSpringBoot3>true</useSpringBoot3>
<useSpringController>true</useSpringController>
<openApiNullable>false</openApiNullable>
<performBeanValidation>true</performBeanValidation>
```

It generates only `@NotNull` annotation in model, for required String field in spec,
I have no idea how to generate `@NotBlank` also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So at this point openapi-generator doesn't use @NotBlank and @NotEmpty annotations, only @NotNull. But it can be done via:

```
x-field-extra-annotation: "@jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank"
```

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/71526062/2728393